# Listar Banco de dados com Java ou PHP

Tags: php, java, sql

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de um aplicação mostrar todos os bancos de dados de uma conexão?

Atualmente uso o comando:

```
select
     *
from
     information_schema.TABLES;
```

Comment: Não é só executar esta query pela aplicação?

Comment: banco de dados ou tabelas?

Comment: se for todos os banco de dados é `SHOW DATABASES` (PHP/MYSQL) (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-databases.html)

Answer (score 1):

é so usar o `SHOW DATABASES` pelo menos comigo funcionou assim, usando PHP e mysql